# How to set up tag search in joomla 3x?

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, extensions, tags, search

Joomla has standart tag search module, when i use it result is list of articles titles.

[image]

How to set up a search on the tags so it gave a list of previews of articles with the headline, text and photo like in this creenshot?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need create an [override](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides) for this results layout:

Go to **Extensions** > **Templates** 
- In left menu select **Templates** under **Styles**
- Select your template name
- Select **Create Overrides** Tab
- In **Components** Column select **com_search** > **search**

Now you can find the files in this path:

*/templates/your_template/html/com_search/search/**default_results.php***

From here you can create your changes
Best Regards!